# How covert csv file into arff in Java?

Tags: java, csv, weka, arff

When I am trying to convert CSV File into ARFF I get following error message. How can I solve this ?

```
---Registering Weka Editors---
    Trying to add database driver (JDBC): RmiJdbc.RJDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
    Trying to add database driver (JDBC): jdbc.idbDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
    Trying to add database driver (JDBC): com.mckoi.JDBCDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
    Trying to add database driver (JDBC): org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute names are not unique! Causes: 'þÿÿÿ' 'á' '°' '=' '$' '$' '$' '$' '$' '$' '$' '$' '$' '$' '-' '$' '$' '$' '* ' '-' '-' 
        at weka.core.Instances.<init>(Instances.java:252)
        at weka.core.converters.CSVLoader.readHeader(CSVLoader.java:979)
        at weka.core.converters.CSVLoader.readStructure(CSVLoader.java:610)
        at weka.core.converters.CSVLoader.getStructure(CSVLoader.java:595)
        at weka.core.converters.CSVLoader.getDataSet(CSVLoader.java:628)
        at ConvertToArff.Convert(ConvertToArff.java:22)
        at ConvertToArff.main(ConvertToArff.java:35)
```

Comment: I don't understand how this question could get two upvotes ...

Answer (score 0):

According to your exception, one of your attributes has multiple labels of the same name.  If they can be kept unique, this issue should continue no further.

If this is not the issue, please post more code and/or data (it is very difficult to diagnose with just an exception).

Hope this Helps!